# Grouped Bar Graph from Unequal Vectors

Tags: r, graphing

I'm trying to create a grouped ("side-by-side") bar graph in R for four vectors of unequal length. Each vector has "scores" for a particular process, and while the vectors are not exactly the same length, they're all pretty close. For example, it may be something like:

```
Length of V1 = 1149
Length of V2 = 1151
Length of V3 = 1148
Length of V4 = 1153
```

I've found plenty of solutions on SO about making grouped bar graphs, but none that show how to do so after combining vectors of unequal length. In this case, I only have the values in the vectors themselves - I don't have anything to relate them to each other with (time series, etc). Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add NaN's to all the shorter vectors, so that they have the same length (1153), then you can plot it with bar(...'stacked'), it will ignore the NaN values and not produce an error about unequal lengths.

edit: oops i was looking for matlab problems didnt realize you are asking about R, but maybe there is an equivalent solution...